# How to get the value of jquery autocomplete with change value for other input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I already have product_name value that is create by jquery autocomplete.
but i can't get the full value of the productName.

Example Hello World

when i type hell in the input and click on the Hello World in the product name input field.
I just get the value of hell that i type.
I want to get the full value of the productname.

Html

```
<tbody id="row_container">

<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="product_type" class="product_type">
            <option value="custom">Custom</option>
            <option value="tour_package">Tour</option>
            <option value="nontour_product">Generic</option>

        </select>    
    </td>
    <td><input name='product_name' id='product_name' class='product_name'/></td>
    <td><input name='description' id='description' class='description'/></td>

</tr>
```

jquery

```
$('#row_container').on('click','.product_name', function(){ 
        var productName = $(this).val();
        console.log(productName);

});
```

Comment: Add the script to your question which contains `autComplete()`

Answer (score 1):

i dont know which auto complete library you are using.In this demo im using typeahead.js.
Hope you find it useful.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#row_container').on('click','.product_name', function(){ 

        var productName = $(this).val();
        console.log(productName);

});
$('input.product_name').typeahead({
      name: 'products',
      local: ["apple", "orange","ball","cat"]
});
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/31SdsF2FqoMBl4ZKi827?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

did you close table tags correctly?

```
</tbody></table>
```

it works to me: http://jsfiddle.net/hB6kg/1/